# PHP redirect header

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am working on a web portal for a school project and I need to create a signature. I have a table called student in my database where I have supervisor_id_dos and supervisor_id_sup2.

Now I want to use session to check who  is logged in and direct them to a particular page to sign but the if statement doesn't run, it skips and loads the page under the else statement.

I don't know what am doing right

```
 <?php   



include "connect.php";  



session_start();    <br/>



$sql = "SELECT * from student WHERE level ='user' and (supervisor_id_dos='$_SESSION[username]'OR      supervisor_id_sup2='$_SESSION[username]')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


$row = mysql_num_rows($result);  
if($row){ 
    if($_SESSION["username"] = $row["supervisor_id_dos"])
    { 

    header("Location: dos_sign.php"); 
    } 

else{ 
    header("Location: wrong_sign.php");
}    


}  






?>
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPDDQ.png)

Comment: you're mixing MySQL APIs for one thing and thanks for the lovely screenshot of "code".

Comment: First thing, you are using `mysql` and `mysqli` at the same time. And your if condition is wrong, it needs to be `==`.

Comment: [Learning PHP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-best-way-to-learn-php--net-22287)

Comment: I've made the corrections but now it skips the if statement to the else statement

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `==` instead of `=` inside `IF` statements to compare values, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is more information about PHP Comparison Operators

Try to put `exit()` after use of `header()` redirect, it will prevent the rest of php code to get executed

Then, I think you also have an error in your `MySQL` query where you don't have a space before `OR`

Comment: you missed something very important.

Comment: I've done that but it returns with --- Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fyp/sign_check.php on line 8

and line 8 is the $row = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: There, you see what I mean? ^ ^ ^ and it won't stop there neither.

Comment: I'll just leave this link here.. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/computers-software/programming/php.html

Comment: I appreciate your concern, I'll take a careful study of the link you sent. But I've to to fix this script soon because my project is due soon.